# Copy one jar file into .another jar file in Scala

Tags: scala, jar

I have to change the contents of .config file in my .jar file, I have copied the contents of config file from .jar folder and created one .config file outside the .jar file location.Now I created one method which is taking my `.jar-file`, `.config file name` and an `inputstream to this newly created .config file`. The method creates a temporary .jar file with contents copied from original jar and finally renames temp .jar file to original one and deleting original one. It is working fine but the .jar file created is corrupted and is not opening. What might be the issue, here is my code...

```
def createNewJar(jarToEdit:String, entryToEdit: String, isp:InputStream) = {

     val tempJar = File.createTempFile(jarToEdit, null, new File("/home/administrator/Sources/Scala/rationaltab-launchpad"))

     val jar = new JarFile(jarToEdit)
     val entries = jar.entries()
     val buffer = new Array[Byte](1024)
     val newJar = new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(tempJar))
     var delFlag = false
     var bytesRead = 0

     while(entries.hasMoreElements) {

            try {

                val entry = entries.nextElement()
                val is = jar.getInputStream(entry)
                var newEntry = entry

                if (newEntry.getName.equals(entryToEdit)) {
                   newEntry = new JarEntry(entryToEdit)
                 }

               newJar.putNextEntry(newEntry)

               if (!newEntry.getName.equals(entryToEdit)) {
                 while ( {bytesRead = is.read(buffer); bytesRead != -1 }) {
                    newJar.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                  }
               }

               if (newEntry.getName.equals(entryToEdit)) {

                 while ( { bytesRead = isp.read(buffer); bytesRead != -1 }) {
                   newJar.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                 }
               }
             newJar.closeEntry()

      } catch { case e :Exception => e.printStackTrace() }

     }

    delFlag = true
    if (delFlag) {
       val origFile = new File(jarToEdit)
       origFile.delete()
       tempJar.renameTo(origFile)
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you use Java 7+ as a base, use the zip FileSystem provider

Comment: @fge I am using Scala.

Comment: Then what? Scala uses the JRE as a base

Comment: @fge I know, but what could have gone wrong in my code above

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe you need to call `close()` on the Streams.

Comment: @Seth, I tried to close is.close() in every if block but still the same issue...